# PrimeFaces elements that need h:form to be updated

Tags: forms, jsf-2, primefaces

I need list of primefaces elements that need to be wraped by `<h:form>` in order to be updated by any action of `<p:ajax>`
some primeface elements even if they have id and in `<p:ajax update="thisID">` it still needs an `<h:form>` with an id in ordered to be updated so which elements need `<h:form>` and whick not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every component submitting/receiving Content from/to a backing bean needs to be wrapped by `<h:form>`.

So everything you want to update or every Button / Link setting something needs to be inside a form. Also this isn't a Primefaces thing. This rules apply for normal JSF too.

Comment: thanks but if i want to update values with a checkbox for example and not a button/link<br> although i have seen some outside JSF source codes where they update elements without h:form so i think that some JSF elements acts as h:form so that is my question is there any JSF elements that acts like h:form if yes what are they??

Comment: Everything receiving content from a backing bean doesn't need to be wrapped in a form at all. Only content which needs to be submitted needs to be wrapped in a form. It works also exactly that way in plain vanilla HTML (which is what JSF ultimately also produces).

Answer (score 6):

To the point, all components implementing [the `EditableValueHolder` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) and [the `ActionSource` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) needs to be enclosed in [an `UIForm` component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html).

In the aforelinked Javadocs you can find in the "All Known Implementing Classes" indications which components implement them. If you look closely, then you'll notice that it are all input components like `inputText`, `selectOneMenu`, etc and command components like `commandLink`, `commandButton`, etc. In the [PrimeFaces API documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/), for example the [`InputText`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/inputtext/InputText.html) which represents the `<p:inputText>` implements `EditableValueHolder`, so it should be placed in a form.

It's also exactly the same rerequirement as in [plain vanilla HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) has, the HTML `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc should go in a `<form>` in order to get value to be sent to the server side. HTML is also what JSF ultimately produces, after all.

As to updating elements by ajax, it's not true that the to-be-updated components *needs* to be placed inside a form. You can perfectly update content which is outside the current form. You can even update other forms.

Comment: it seems like the prime faces has an additional requirement that the to-be-updatable components must be rendered in the original  request for them to be updated by ajax response. in essense, this prevents the use case where a certain section of the page, which has its own form, gets rendered based on the initial data submitted by the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight modification to PatrickT's Answer. You are able to update things outside the form also. But data you want to submit should be part of the form afaik.

```
<p:messages id="outsideForm" showDetail="true"></p:messages>
<h:form id="kalle">
<p:messages id="insideForm" showDetail="true"></p:messages>
    <p:inputText required="true"></p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" update=":outsideForm,insideForm"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: thanks but i prefer if there is a list of elements like the <p:messages> that you included

Comment: tbh, i dont know of any components that need to be inside a form to be updated. Only components that want to submit data need to be inside a form. But Guess we need to wait for a jsf-expert to weigh in on this :)